# node-soap: createClient is not a function

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, protractor

I am trying to consume webservice using node-soap
I have referred [github](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) example.

Below is the code:

[image: code]

And this is the error I get:

[image: error]

Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first line, you should have:

`var soap = require('soap');`

NOT

`var soap = require('node-soap');`